# Changing and storing value from radio buttons

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, radio-button

I have been trying to create an age filter using radio buttons(the code should show only the specific age group upon clicking a certain radio button) and using an imported JSON file. For the radio button, there is an age range such as 0-20, 20-30, etc.

What I'm attempting to figure is how can I remove the character "-" from the radio button's input value, store the remaining values such as "0" and "20", and compare them with my JSON file?

Below is what I have:

HTML

```
<h3 id="title3">Age</h3>
  <div class="radioButtonBoxMenu">
    <label><input name="radiob" type="radio" value="0-20">0-20</label><br>
    <label><input name="radiob" type="radio" value="20-30">20-30</label><br>
    <label><input name="radiob" type="radio" value="30-40">30-40</label><br>
    <label><input name="radiob" type="radio" value="40">40+</label><br>
  </div>
```

A small portion of the JSON file

```
"nodes":[
          { "id": "1", "name": "John", "age": "31", "gender": "M"},
          { "id": "2", "name": "Emily", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
          { "id": "3", "name": "Crystal", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
          { "id": "4", "name": "Himiko", "age": "23", "gender": "F" }
        ]
```

JavaScript

```
    //Code for radio button filter on age range
    d3.selectAll("input[name=radiob]").on("change", function(d) {

        var value = this.value;
        var age = document.getElementsByName("radiob");
        var ageBracket;

        node.style("opacity", 1);
        link.style("opacity", 1);


        for (var i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
            if (age[i].checked) {
                ageBracket = age[i].value;

                if (ageBracket == "0-20") {
                  //Do something...

                }

            }
        }


        if (value !== "") {
            node.filter(function(d) {
                    return d.age != value;
                })
                .style("opacity", "0.2");

            link.filter(function(d) {
                    return d.source.age != value &&
                        d.target.age != value;
                })
                .style("opacity", "0.2");

            link.filter(function(d) {
                    return d.source.age == value ||
                        d.target.age == value;
                })
                .style("opacity", "1");
        }

    });
```

Comment: I added answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your for loop with something like this should do it:

```
var matchingRows;
for (var i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
    if (age[i].checked) {
        ageBracket = age[i].value.split('-');
        matchingRows = jsonRows.filter( function( row ) {
            return row.age >= ageBracket[0] && row.age <= ageBracket[1];
        } );
        break;
    }
}
console.dir( matchingRows );
```

The split method will create an array from your range string, turning '0-20' into [ 0, 20 ]. Then you can filter the data from your JSON object (assuming those rows are in an array—if not, use Array.from() to convert them). This should give you an array of rows that match the selected radio button.

Comment: Good answer, but you're missing two things: 1. you have to convert the strings to numbers (like `["0", "20"]` to `[0, 20]`), otherwise the comparison will fail. It can be just `+ageBracket[0]` etc, with the unary plus. 2. it is `-`, not `_`.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't need to convert the strings to numbers to make the comparison.  25 > ["20", "30"][ 0 ] evaluates to true, 25 > ["20", "30"][ 1 ] is false. (Though I'm certainly not opposed to converting it explicitly)  Thanks for pointing out the wrong horizontal line character!

Comment: It's my bad, I thought that `row.age` was a string as well, and if that was the case the comparison would fail. But since `row.age` is a number the string is automatically coerced to a number, so no need for the unary plus, I was wrong... anyway, it's always a good thing explicitly converting strings to numbers, you never know how someone will deal with that string later in the code...

Comment: Hello, for the "jsonRows", I replaced it with "d.filter(function(d) { return d.age >= ageBracket[0] && d.age <= ageBracket[1]" and it has given me this error: "TypeError: data is undefined"...

Comment: It looks like you're using d to represent two different values. The d that you have as d.filter should contain the array of objects called 'nodes' in your JSON file. The d within the filter function will represent a single one of those objects at a time as the filter function loops through the array. What is the value of d before you call the filter method on it?

Answer (score -1):

**Demo**

```js
var ageBracket = '0-20';

var nodes = [
          { "id": "1", "name": "John", "age": "31", "gender": "M"},
          { "id": "2", "name": "Emily", "age": "18", "gender": "F" },
          { "id": "3", "name": "Crystal", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
          { "id": "4", "name": "Himiko", "age": "23", "gender": "F" }
        ];

// Split the input radio value and convert the elements of an array into Number.
var ageRange = ageBracket.split('-').map(Number);

// Apply filter() method on nodes array to filter out the data between the ageRange.  
var selectedRangeDetails = nodes.filter(obj => obj.age >= ageRange[0] && obj.age <= ageRange[1]);

console.log("selectedRangeDetails", selectedRangeDetails);
```